# Create a zarr store for images read with openslide

Tags: python, zarr, openslide

I want to operate on some images using dask/zarr, but these images are large pyramid TIFF's that can't be read by either directly and need to be read by a software like OpenSlide. At the moment my strategy has been to create a process that takes the image and reads it chunk by chunk into a new zarr array. However, I found this [napari plug in](https://github.com/manzt/napari-lazy-openslide) online where they created a zarr store that can read from the WSI directly.

In this code they create a pyramid zarr file, and it doesn't seem to work on my images. I would like to use zarr.open to access just the highest resolution (level 0) array through zarr/dask as a YxXx3 matrix (RGB).

Here is the code I have tried if it is useful

```
from zarr.storage import BaseStore
import zarr
from openslide import OpenSlide
import numpy as np

class OpenSlideStore(BaseStore):
    def __getitem__(self, key: str = None):
        if key is None:
            raise KeyError()
        y, x = key.split('.')
        
        try:
            int(y)
            int(x)
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("Invalid key format. Key should be in the format 'y.x'")
        
        chunk = self._slide.read_region((int(x), int(y)), 0, (self._chunk_size, self._chunk_size)).convert('RGB')
        return np.array(chunk)
        
    def __setitem__(self, key: str = None, value: bytes = None):
        raise NotImplementedError()
    
    def __delitem__(self, key: str = None):
        raise NotImplementedError()
    
    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return int(self._slide.dimensions[0] / self._chunk_size) * int(self._slide.dimensions[1] / self._chunk_size)
    
    def __iter__(self):
        for y in range(0, self._slide.dimensions[1], self._chunk_size):
            for x in range(0, self._slide.dimensions[0], self._chunk_size):
                yield self._slide.read_region((x, y), 0, (self._chunk_size, self._chunk_size)).convert('RGB')
```

Comment: Please specify "doesn't seem to work on my images". You could also try [tifffile](https://github.com/cgohlke/tifffile/blob/00a3c6a7b7adfc886cb1e59e423d13612b376d68/tifffile/tifffile.py#L711-L730) to access the image data in pyramidal TIFF using the zarr store interface.